# What does a junction do inside a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, application-note

Today I found an application note that stunned me.

Onsemi is quite a big manufacturer for discrete power devices. So I was astonished to read within that [Application note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9042-D.PDF) about junction temperatures inside a MOSFET.

As a MOSFET does not have a junction as a functional element, I'm asking myself, what do they mean? Is it just imprecise language or has it some background. A colleague searched and found the word mentioned within a datasheet for a MOSFET from TI, so it's not completely uncommon.

Back to the AN. The graphic illustrations insinuate that junction is here a pars pro toto for the whole die. So why don't the use the term "die" instead?

I think of the following possible explanations:

1. When talking about thermal issues the wording forged in bipolar days was transferred to the field effect ages without caring about the meaning of the word
2. Similar, but quite not the same, someone considered the source-body- or source-drain-junctions as something worth referring to. Perhaps they are also thermal very active? I don't think so as most of conduction losses should occur within the channel
3. Junction has just a broader meaning than I thought, encompassing all current conducting or blocking parts of discrete semiconductors. (I've got to add, I'm not a native speaker)

I may miss some historical details. I know this question might be off-topic because it could solicitate opinions, doesn't deal with a material engineering problem and might as well be completely unanswerable.
But I think, this is an engineering related question, because it is vital to have a common terminology in engineering. Furthermore engineering history is not completely irrelevant for solving current problems.

Comment: In functional terms, the 'junction' is the tiny part of the die that gets hot when there's current and a voltage drop. The boundary of that region is defined very differently for BJTs and FETs

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes, that's what it is apparently meant to mean here. But in the truest sense of the word a junction is the plane where differently doped regions touch.

Comment: *As a MOSFET does not have a junction as a functional element* I'm not sure I fully agree with that. The Drain and Source areas must be isolated from the Bulk and this is done using PN junctions. My guess is that the term "junction" is historic and might originate from the PN diode. I would simply interpret "junction" as "die" and move on. Whether any heat is generated in a junction or elsewhere in the die, doesn't matter that much to the user in my view.

Comment: The term Junction Temperature is frequently used to mean Die temperature, even for devices that don't actually have any - such as CMOS ics.

Comment: I'm sure the manufacturers are borrowing from Humpty Dumpty, "when I use a word it means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less." Does 'junction' have a 'truest sense' of the word. Do we care. You knew what they were referring to. The bit that gets hot is the first to go bang during overload, it's the bit the thermal impedance is quoted from to tab. They could have called it 'the important bit you must not let get too hot' regardless of whether it's defined by the mobile boundary of a depletion region, or PN diffusion regions. But that's a bit long.

Comment: It has a name, but I can't remember, just like the icon of the "save" button is still being a diskette in modern programs.

Comment: Isn't that simply a common shorthand term for "internal temperature of the silicon structures", coming from earlier inventions like Diodes/BJTs/etc?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're being unduly picky- it's only a datasheet- everyone knows what it means, like 'dialing' a phone with a touch screen. (Almost) all semiconductors have junctions somewhere (maybe some silicon-on-sapphire or similar exotic types do not), and junction leakage is an important specification in junction-isolated semiconductors.

Even in a formal document such as IEC 60747 they refer to the virtual channel temperature of a MOSFET, but the symbol used is 'j'!

Answer (score -1):

FETs within wells have created a parasitic bipolar transistor. If the well (the bulk) is flooded with charge and if enough resistance exists within that well to cause a diode drop of voltage, then the parasitic bipolar may enter the POSITIVE FEEDBACK region of BIPOLAR_SNAPBACK.

At high temperatures, the required current becomes smaller, because resistance increases and the diode voltage has dropped 2 milliVolts per degree C.

How to flood a well with charge? TRANSIENTS.

Thus measuring DC_leakage of the FET does not constitute adequate characterization for TRANSIENTS.

At one time our most profitable product, even legacy masks, were having abnormal field failures. Had something changed in the FAB, or was that particular customer abusing the Silicon?

Investigating, teasing the dragon's tail with onset/quench/onset/quench snapback waveforms, I concluded the DRC rules were derived from legacy DC_leakage measurements.

Solution? Impose much denser Well Ties, to capture the transient charges.

Why? at one volt per nanosecond VDD ringing, 100pF C_well_drain tells us there is the need to grab onto 0.1 amp of charge injection.

Or that bipolar_snapback becomes your nightmare.